# UINavigationBar control, not picking up self.title or self.navigationItem.title

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have a UINavigationBar control at the top of my View and in my associated controller I've tried setting self.navigationItem.title and self.title but neither modify the title of the NavigationBar.

The only thing that works is to set the title in Interface Builder:

[image: Navigation Item]

How can I make this work programmatically.

Comment: have tried self.navigationcotroller.navigationitem.title?

Comment: Can you post the exact code you used to set the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a view controller's `title` or `navigationItem.title` only works if the view controller is in a navigation controller. If you are not using a `UINavigationController`, but are just sticking a `UINavigationBar` on the view controller, then you must assign the view controller's `navigationItem` to the navbar.

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Some Title";
self.myNavBar.items = @[ self.navigationItem ];
```

where `self.myNavBar` should be replaced with the actual reference you have to the `UINavigationBar`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this..it will work.

```
@interface NewViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navbar;
}
```

Now in xib file click on navigation Item and give IBOutlet Connection to navbar.
In Your .m file put this simple code.

```
navbar.title = @"Your Title";
```